# copyValue from another collection in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Can i Copy Some Field from collection to another collection?

I want copy values of bar to foo collection, but i don't want type filed, and I want insert in foo e new _id e extra field (userId) ( then i use Node.js)

```
collection bar
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77777777ffffff9999999999"),
    "type" : 0,
    "name" : "Default",
    "index" : 1,
    "layout" : "1",    
}


collection foo
{
    "_id" : NEW OBJECT ID,
//    "type" : 0, NO IN THIS COLLECTION
    "userId" : ObjectId("77777777ffffff9999999911"),
    "name" : "Default",
    "index" : 1,
    "layout" : "1",    
}
```

I try with `db.bar.copyTo("foo");` but copy entire collection

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is probably your best option. But when you don't want the new field in your collection, then just remove it using [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/):

```js
db.foo.update({ },{ "$unset": { "type": 1 } },false,true)
```

That will remove the field from all documents in your new collection in one statement.

In future releases from 2.6 and upwards you can also do this using [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.bar.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "userId" : 1
        "name" : 1
        "index" : 1
        "layout" : 1
    }},
    { "$out": "foo" }
])
```

The new [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) method sends the output of the aggregation statement to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy fields from one collection to another by using

```
 db.copyFromCollection.find().forEach(function(x){

    db.copyToCOllection.update(
    {"_id" : ObjectId("53205a4a14952bee39f3376e")}, //some condition for update

    { $set:{parameterOfCopyToCollection:x.parameterOfCopyFromCollection}
});

});
```

Here we iterate through the data by using the above function.We iterate through the collection from which we want to copy the data and then inside the function we update the document to which we want to add/update that data.